# How to uniquely identify an android device, regardless of platform like phone, tablet or watch?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier, mac-address, serial-number, wearables

Some people suggested the serial number others mentioned the MAC address, what I want is something that uniquely identifies an android device whether it is a phone, tablet or watch. My app itself is for wearable devices, I am supposed to make it send the location among some other data when the app is used but I need something to be able to tell the different watches apart.

Any links or resources that go on how this can be done is appreciated, but I ask for it to be something up to date because most things I found are decade old.

Answer (score 1):

With the current restrictions in android Serial number and MAC address are locked down among other items that people have used for unique device id.

The recommended method is to use [Instance ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id) but be aware that this can change so you have to have a mechanism to update it.

Another method you can use is to create a file on the device that has some unique ID in it that you can look for but the file can always be messed with by a user so you have to be aware of that too

Comment: When you say locked down what do you mean? It won't appear when the app gets published? I mean I am able to display the MAC address, or am I missing something?

Comment: meaning you get nothing back (null) or just static data that means nothing

Comment: you should read through the android security changes over the last few versions

Comment: I have looked around and I saw what  you mean. Maybe I need to clarify a bit what I want exactly. I want to generate something like a report with the data chosen by the user as well as the user's location whenever the app is used. In this case would the GUID be the my best bet? What I mean is would it be unique to the device the app is on so that I can differentiate between different users?

Comment: sounds like that would work depending on where you store it which is where my file suggestion comes into play. You store that id in your app somewhere its gone when the user uninstalls so you will have to create a new one if they install it again

Comment: so something that gets generated once and saved on the app. But when the app is uninstalled, that would get wiped out so it would generate a new one if gets installed again.